# Task manager that represent the processes of your app

Tags: android, performance, taskmanager, process-monitoring

I'm trying to monitor my app's processes, like GPS,Google location, and more. and I already found some good task managers that are showing those processes in the "running processes" list, but non of them is show the relation between the processes. For Ex. if my app "abc" is using gps then I would like to have this relation in the task manager. gps---> "abc"

Does someone know about task manager that support it?

Those do not:
Android task manager, Task Manager, Advanced Task Manager, Android Assistant, Super tool box 10+

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does someone know about task manager that support it?

No, because that's not possible. A third party app has no way of determining the existence or nature of inter-process communication between other processes.

A sufficiently-modified ROM can probably accomplish this, though I have no idea if such a ROM exists.